# How to access loop and normal data in mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TSICompanyDashboard.Models.tblValuationVechicleImage>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
            VALUATION REPORT OF VEHICLE
        </div>
       
      <div class="text-center" style="font-size:20px;">
        (CONFIDENTIAL FOR EXCLUSIVE USE OF @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tblValuationVechJob.tblBank.BankName)
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="background-color:lightgrey; font-weight:bold;">
        <div class="col-md-3">Date: @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Report No: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblValuationVechJob.tblCity.CityName)/@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblValuationVechJob.ReportType)/@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblValuationVechJob.tblBank.BankCode)/@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblValuationVechJob.tblCustomer.Code)/@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblValuationVechJob.Id)/2020</div>
    </div>

        @{
        int groupings = 2;
        var grouped = Model.Select((x, i) => new { x, i = i / groupings })
                      .GroupBy(x => x.i, x => x.x);
    }
    <table id="memberlist" class="table" >
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var items in grouped )
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        <td class="col-lg-6 text-center"><img src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" height="400" width="400" /><br />(@item.ImageType)</td>

                    }

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <p style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;">FOR: TRISTAR INTERNATIONAL CONSULTANT (PVT.) LTD</p>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <p style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;"> __________________________<br />Authorized Signature</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my controller:

```
using Rotativa.MVC;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TSICompanyDashboard.Models;

namespace TSICompanyDashboard.Controllers
{
    public class ValuationVehicleImageController : Controller
    {
        private TSIDellEntities db = new TSIDellEntities();

       public ActionResult ImageReport(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                var tblValVechimg = db.tblValuationVechicleImages.SqlQuery("select * from tblValuationVechicleImage where ValuationVechicJobId=" +id);
                if (tblValVechimg == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                var report = new PartialViewAsPdf("~/Views/ValuationVehicleImage/ImageReport.cshtml", tblValVechimg);
                return report;
    
            }
        }
```

and

```
namespace TSICompanyDashboard.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    
    public partial class tblValuationVechicleImage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ValuationVechicJobId { get; set; }
        public string ImageType { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
        public virtual tblValuationVechJob tblValuationVechJob { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this:

[image]

[image]

I have relation with tables bank->ValJob->ValImage

I am new to this forum and MVC
thanks in advance

Comment: `how can I achieve this` What you want to achieve?

Comment: You can either set the date value in a ViewBag and use it in the view to display the value. `ViewBag.DateValue = DateTime.Now;`.  and use in view as `@ViewBag.DateValue`

Comment: Other approach is to create a class with one DateTime property and one List property. And use that class as Model in the view.

Comment: I am talking about Report Number

Comment: My Report Number consist of city,customer name,job id from their respective tables

Comment: You need to create a class with string property to store report number and List<tblValuationVechicleImage> property to store the image collection. In the controller action you should create object of this  class, populate the properties and pass it to your view. In the view you should change the model type to that of class instead of  `IEnumerable<TSICompanyDashboard.Models.tblValuationVechicleImage>`.